# convert an excel number to a short text in access VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2016

Hi I have a table in access that gets its data from excel like so

```
Public Sub ImportExcel(fileName As String)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "JobNumber", fileName, False, "K2:K2"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "DateTable", fileName, False, "C3:C3"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Supplier", fileName, False, "C5:C5"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Graphic", fileName, False, "C6:C6"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Shift", fileName, False, "L1:L1"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Size", fileName, False, "L3:L3"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "RollInfo", fileName, False, "B10:F102"
Call CheckNullValues
Call AddLookUps
Call AddPressData
Call deleteZigZagTables
End Sub
```

I'm have problems with the converting the value of C6 in excel to text in access what I'm currently doing is this

```
Public Sub AddPressData()
Dim SQLstring As String
Dim GraphicString As String
Dim rst As Recordset

SQLstring = "SELECT F1 FROM GRAPHIC;"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLstring)
If Not IsNumeric(rst.Fields(0).Value) Then
    SQLstring = "INSERT INTO Press ( MasterRollNumber, JobNumber, DateDay, Shift, Supplier, Graphic, [Size], [Linear Measure], [Pallet Number] ) SELECT RollInfo.F1, JobNumber.F1, DateTable.F1, Shift.F1, Supplier.F1, Graphic.F1, (Size.F1), RollInfo.F3, RollInfo.F4 FROM RollInfo, JobNumber, DateTable, Shift, Supplier, Graphic, [Size] WHERE NOT ISNULL(RollInfo.F1);"
    CurrentDb.Execute SQLstring, dbFailOnError
Else
    SQLstring = "INSERT INTO Press ( MasterRollNumber, JobNumber, DateDay, Shift, Supplier, Graphic, [Size], [Linear Measure], [Pallet Number] ) SELECT RollInfo.F1, JobNumber.F1, DateTable.F1, Shift.F1, Supplier.F1, CSTR(Graphic.F1), (Size.F1), RollInfo.F3, RollInfo.F4 FROM RollInfo, JobNumber, DateTable, Shift, Supplier, Graphic, [Size] WHERE NOT ISNULL(RollInfo.F1);"
    CurrentDb.Execute SQLstring, dbFailOnError
End If
End Sub
```

Most of the time graphic is a string but every once and a while it can be a number and when I run the code when its a number it will just leave the field blank for each record.

If Anyone has any suggestions that will be a big help
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but this is the way I would do it because then you wont need the `If` statement at all.

```
 Graphic.F1 & ''
```

When you concatenate a string with a number, the result is a string.

`CSTR` is a VBA function, and you are trying to use it in a SQL statement.

Comment: perhaps something else is going on because that did not help. the field graphic has a relationship with the table graphics that stores all the types of graphics and it adds numbers using the STR() function

Comment: Graphic.F1 & ' Graphic'  works not sure why Graphic.F1 & '' doesn't but I think that adding graphic to the end of the number will work for my needs thank you

Answer (score 0):

In constructing your SQL string you can use the concatenation operator and the string conversion function, for example:

```
s = "Hello " & CStr(Cells(1, 1)) & "world"
```

Note: I strongly suggest you format your SQL string so it will be better readable. For example:

```
    SQLstring = _
        "INSERT INTO Press( MasterRollNumber, JobNumber, DateDay, Shift, Supplier, Graphic, [Size], [Linear Measure], [Pallet Number] ) " & _
        "      SELECT RollInfo.F1, JobNumber.F1, DateTable.F1, Shift.F1, Supplier.F1, Graphic.F1, (Size.F1), RollInfo.F3, RollInfo.F4 " & _
        "      FROM RollInfo, JobNumber, DateTable, Shift, Supplier, Graphic, [Size] " & _
        "      WHERE NOT ISNULL(RollInfo.F1);"
```